# Pass extra data to an entity

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I'm currently developping a Media Behavior in order to attach media to models.
I want to process the file (upload) in the Media model ; that way, everytime I upload a file, it is directly associated to a file.

In cakephp2.0, I directly passed in the data array an extra field 'file' from where I could extract the file and do my processing.
I tried here to do in my behavior :

```
$entity = $this->_table->Medias->newEntity(array(
    'path' => WWW_ROOT . $config['path'],
    'file' => $data[$field],
    'field' => $field
));
```

Where the `file` key isn't related to any field in the table. But it doesn't get through and I can't get it back in my back `beforeSave()` lifecycle callback in my Medias Model.

How can I pass it to my model in a proper way ?

Answer (score 1):

By default Entities are protected against mass-assignment attacks. This means that when creating entities out of an array you need to explicitly tell the entity or the `newEntity()` what fields are accessible.

Please read the documentation on mass assignment:

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#mass-assignment

You can also tell the `newEntity` and `patchEntity` methods what the accessible fields list should be. Please read the documentation on how to use the `fieldList` and `accessibleFields` options for those methods:

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#converting-request-data-into-entities

Finally, another reason some data might not reach the entity is validation. Make sure your fields are passing the validation you have for them, as if they fail any of the rules, they will not be copied to the entity.